# How to install WhatsApp on a separate drive on windows10?

Tags: hard-drive, installation, disk-space, whatsapp

Since I don't have sufficient space on the main Os drive (Drive C). I need to install WhatsApp on another drive. But when I run the setup file, it doesn't ask me where to install the software. It just automatically installs it on "Drive C"! Any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're short of space to install such simple software then where to install it is the least of your problems.

Comment: The problem is not the software itself. After the installation and using it for a while, WhatsApp keeps downloaded pictures and videos which takes a great amount of the drive and since I have a 128gb SSD, the space is really limited.

Comment: Often software has "express" and "custom" installation options. If that is the case, chose "custom" so you get to chose where to install it. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-apps-separate-drive-windows-10
https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-default-install-location-of-apps-in-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks, but WhatsApp setup doesn't come with custom installation. Once you click on setup, it installs the software immediately!

Answer (score -1):

To install whatsapp on a separate drive, first install whatsapp on the pc. Then you also install Easeus todo pc trans (from getintopc that is where ypu will get the premium version for free). After installation you can then migrate whatsapp desktop to the separate using Easeus todo Pctrans.Do not start whatsapp from the desktop it wont open rather open or create a shortcut from the migrated whatsapp exe file on the separate drive. Hope this info was helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).